# preventing google to detect your traffic by vb browser

Tags: vb.net, browser

I have this problem for a long time and I test a lot of ways to fix it but I can't. my main problem is that when my vb webbrowser search in google , after a while google ditect unusual traffic from my computer network (like google say) so I forced to type the characters of image google send me every 5 minutes and try again the last search.

Does anyone know a way to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use the [Google APIs](http://code.google.com/).  You can download them from their site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem solved but can you guide me how to search unlimited with google apis. An example can help me alot. Thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately it's not something I use, but this site seems to be ok with it: http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2003_06_22_index.html.  Hope this helps.  PS: Notice that there is a 1000 search a day limit on this.

Comment: The link you gave is not about google api for dotnet , it used for web.